# django using object inside templates without using view

Tags: python-3.x, django

Im new to django; I'm using include inside a template that call another template like this

```
{% include "cars_models.html" with user_id=request.user.id %}
```

is there a way to use `Cars.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)` or something like inside the cars_models template direct to get all cars are related to user_id without using views

I'm trying to use cars_models templates inside another templates like widgets for base template. I'm not using any view for my base template

Comment: You can try to use template tag then.

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko I don't understand

Comment: If you cannot use views, but still want to execute python code for the template, you can create your custom template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/.

Comment: @Melvyn is not waht im looking for I'm trying to use car templates inside another templates like a widget not to create another view that return for me the cars

Comment: @Melvyn I don't have any view for the base template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider this custom template tag solution:

1. In the root directory create directory "templatetags". Create file car_tags.py inside the folder, add this code to that file:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

from app_name.models import Car
@register.simple_tag
def car_tag(id):
    return Cars.objects.get(user_id=id)
```

2. Add library with your tag into the settings.py into TEMPLATES/OPTIONS:

```
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'car_tags': 'templatetags.car_tags',
            }
        },
```

3. In your template load your tag at the top of the template: `{% load car_tags %}`
4. Use your tag in your template this way: `{% car_tag request.user.id %}`

Comment: I'm getting this error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unknown parameters: libraries`

Comment: I find the error was missing from django import template

Comment: I did exactly what you said I'm getting this error `Invalid block tag on line 4: 'car_tag'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`. I did try to change to `{{ car_tag request.user.id }}` but I get  `Could not parse the remainder: ' request.user.id' from 'car_tag request.user.id'`

Comment: Please show how you use {% load car_tags %} at the top of your template.

Comment: Please use tag this way {% car_tag request.user.id %}, this is correct. Looks like loading is incorrect.

Comment: Right I had double space between % and car_tag

Comment: No problem! Could you also please add upvote if helped.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use querysets in templates. You need to create one in your views and pass as context to your templates.

But if your models is something like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

You can call all cars related to the logged user in your templates with:

```
{% for car in request.user.car_set.all %}
    <p>{{car}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

Where car_set is the [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/) of you model.

Comment: Can't see what you want. I'm not using any views. You may use car_set.all inside cars_models.

Comment: sorry I didn't get your answer verry well but what I'm trying to do is to use a template like widget inside base template and i'm not using any view for my base template